# Connect Raspberry Pi Pico to 93C46 trought Microwire (3-wire Protocol)

Tags: spi, pi-pico, wiring, micropython, eeprom

i searched to know if someone did that before, but i didn't find anything, some C code to read and write using Arduino, but when i try to convert it i failed because i'm new at MicroPython and Raspberry Pi Pico, this code i get in from different sources in YouTube video where i get that Microwire or (3-wire protocole) is something like SPI protocol,

```
from machine import SPI, Pin
import ustruct
import time
import sys


### Connecting Pins
SK = 2
DI = 3
DO = 4
CS = Pin(5, Pin.OUT, value = 1)

### Variables
REG_READ = 0x02
REG_WRITE = 0x01
REG_WREN = 0x00

### Initialize spi protocole
spi = SPI(0, baudrate = 2000000, polarity = 1, phase = 1, bits = 8, firstbit = SPI.MSB, sck=Pin(SK), mosi=Pin(DI), miso=Pin(DO))

### read data
data = bytearray()
#spi.write_readinto(b'\x00\x00\x00', data)
print(data) # output bytearray(b'')
```

i want to read the ROM of 93C46 which is a 1Kb (1024 byte) , ORG connected to GND which it's 8 bit
that some info about the chip: https://www.circuits-diy.com/93c46-1k-eeprom-datasheet/
[image: 93c46-1Kb-EEPROM]
[image: Wiring Raspberry Pi Pico to 93C46]

any one know how i can reach that?